# Predict when scrolling will start while dragging

Tags: javascript, css, browser

When the user clicks on an element and starts dragging, if they drag near the top or bottom of the viewport then the view scrolls. I'd like to do something *before* the scrolling starts  – by the time the `scroll` event fires it's too late to do what I want to do.

Is it possible to know that the scrolling is about to start? For example:

- Is there something like a `will-scroll` event?
- Or an `auto-scroll-offset` property that says "If the mouse is less than this distance from the start/end of the viewport then start scrolling"?
- Or some other way to guess that scrolling is about to start?

Comment: _"Is there something like a will-scroll event?"_ - how _could_ there possibly be? The user might stop dragging at more or less the exact point, where scrolling would start to occur - in which case any such "look at me, I am Nostradamus-ing the future!" event would be just a liar ...

Comment: The browser performs the scrolling when the mouse enters a zone close to the edge of the viewport, and at that time it could fire a "will-scroll" event.

Comment: But at that point it would be a "_does_-scroll" event.

Answer (score 0):

Event like will-scroll doesn't seems possible without involvement of AI :).

But to do `xyz` thing before scrolling starts you can put in some hacks like -

**Hack 1 -**

1. Put a `dragstart` event listener on draggable element.
2. In `dragstart` listener make your container non scrollable by dynamically updating overflow css property of it.
3. Now as user will keep dragging, the `drag` event listener will be called frequently, In there check if cursor position is very close to bottom/top of container.
4. If it's very close, then do xyz thing and make the container scrollable again by dynamically changing back overflow css property of container.

This will be very quick and user shouldn't notice a lag. Just to be safe, you can listen for `dragend` event and make container scrollable again in there.

Further more if needed, you can maintain a global tracking variable to check if user really scrolls after you do xyz thing, if not then you can revert xyz.

`OR`

**Hack 2 -**

1. Maintain a dummy scrollable div just inside your main scrollable container.
2. Add a `onscroll` listener over that inner div.
3. Now if user starts to drag and if it leads to scroll then `onscroll` event will be fired on this inner div, here you can do xyz thing and programmatically set css `display` property of this div to `none` to hide it.
4. So that any further dragging will start to scroll your actual container.

This will happen very quickly and user won't notice the jerk. As part of cleanup, You can listen for `dragend` event and set back `display` property of inner div to `block` again.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting suggestions. Unfortunately the first one does what I was trying to avoid: it guesses where the browser's natural "scroll zone" is, and that guess could easily be wrong. That's why I was hoping to find an "auto-scroll-offset" property. The second one doesn't work because if the dummy div is just inside the main scrollable container then the dummy div must contain the scrollable container's content divs, and when I hide the dummy I hide the content. Nonetheless I like the general principle of your second idea and will try tweak it to make it work.